Floor drains in basement filling after heavy rain
I need help making sense of some of our basement water problems and some of the plumbing. The ultimate goal is to be able to do a rough-finish on the basement. Rough-finish being, maybe leveling the concrete floor, painting/coating the floor, and adding a bathroom. All that with the understanding that we will probably never get rid of the water problems entirely. It's a 1920's craftsman bungalow with a block foundation.
The main issue is that the floor drains in the basement seem to fill with water after a heavy rain. I suspect that this has to do with the abandoned cast sewer line in the basement floor. My guess is that it was poorly capped, or not capped at all when it was disconnected from the city. Our active sanitary line is PVC and exits about halfway up the basement wall. The water used to overflow onto the basement floor from the drains but now I'll usually just start a siphon from the nearest drain to the ejector pit. The water is colorless and odorless.
We have a traditional sump pit that has tiles running into it and an ejector pit. The ejector pit is currently just handling water from the utility sink and laundry. It does not have a tub or grinder pump, just a cheap sump pump. The actual sump pump is usually running by the time that water in the floor drains become an issue. Though, there is one time that water was almost coming out of the floor drains before any water hit the sump pit after a really heavy downpour.
What is the proper way to diagnose and/or fix this type of issue? I'm tempted to just fill them in with concrete, thinking that it would keep the water outside but I'd just want to make sure that this wouldn't make the water issues worse. You'd think that the water would just redirect to the sump-pit if the groundwater got high enough.
The only alternative that I can think of would be to plumb the closest drain into the ejector pit since it's only like 3' away (the closest to the sump pit is like 14'). This would be similar to plumbing the sump pump into city sanitary though, which technically isn't allowed.

Should probably have a plumber run a camera down those drains.  Simple would be to add a check valve/back flow preventer to the pipe, but might cause problems under the floor if the pipe is not good.  Harder would be to re plumb to the storm(not sewer) drains if any in your location.  That technically might become expensive if not followed.

when was it last time you cleaned (declogged) the floor drains

+1 for @crip659's comment. You want a plumber with a camera that can trace where the drain pipe goes, how far it goes, and what's on the other end.
